# Validator.validate() return null

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, bean-validation, apache-tomee

I got an interresting issue with Bean Validation in TomEE 1.7.0.

I have an @Entity @XmlRootElement (yes I know it's ugly but i had to do this quick).

I use a Bean Validator to validate the beans after the return of the query.

In most of case, all is right. But sometimes the validate method returns null.
And when it happens, all next attents fails (null is always returned).

I have to reboot the application to return to the normal.

```
@Entity
@ReadOnly
@XmlRootElement(name = "repartition")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class RepartitionDTO implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @XmlElement
    private String                      id;

    @XmlElement
    // @GUID(message = GUID_Devis_Incorrect)
    private String                      idDevis;

    @XmlElement
    @NotNull(message = Pourcentage_Incorrect, groups = DevisEnum.GroupeValidation.ALL.class)
    private float                       pourcentage;

    @XmlElement
    // @Min(value = 1, message = Pourcentage_Total_Incorrect)
    @Max(value = 1, message = Pourcentage_Total_Incorrect, groups = DevisEnum.GroupeValidation.ALL.class)
    @NotNull(message = Pourcentage_Total_Incorrect)
    private float                       totalRepartition;

    @XmlElement
    // @GUID(message = GUID_Opportunite_Incorrect)
    private String                      idOpportunite;

    @XmlElement
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull(message = Statut_Incorrect, groups = DevisEnum.GroupeValidation.ALL.class)
    private DevisEnum.StatutDevis       statut;

    @XmlElement
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull(message = Type_Marche_Incorrect, groups = DevisEnum.GroupeValidation.RECURRENT.class)
    private DevisEnum.TypeMarche        typeMarche;

    @XmlElement
    // @GUID(message = GUID_FicheMetier_Incorrect)
    private String                      idFicheMetier;

    @XmlElement
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull(message = Type_Metier_Incorrect, groups = DevisEnum.GroupeValidation.ALL.class)
    private DevisEnum.TypeMetier        typeMetier;

    @XmlElement
    // @GUID(message = GUID_Societe_Incorrect)
    private String                      idSociete;

    @XmlElement
    private String                      identifiantCRM;

    @XmlElement
    private String                      raisonSociale;

    @XmlElement
    private String                      codePostal;

    @XmlElement
    private Float                       montantOffensif;

    @XmlElement
    private Float                       montantDefensif;

    @XmlElement
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull(message = Type_Prestation_Incorrect, groups = DevisEnum.GroupeValidation.ALL.class)
    private DevisEnum.TypePrestation    typePrestation;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @XmlElement
    private Date                        dateRemiseOffre;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @XmlElement
    private Date                        dateCreationDevisCRM;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @XmlElement
    private Date                        dateModificationDevisCRM;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @XmlElement
    @NotNull(message = Date_Signature_Incorrecte, groups = DevisEnum.GroupeValidation.ALL.class)
    private Date                        dateSignature;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @XmlElement
    @NotNull(message = Date_DebutPrestation_Incorrecte,
            groups = DevisEnum.GroupeValidation.ALL.class)
    private Date                        dateDebutPrestation;

    @XmlElement
    @Min(value = 1, message = Duree_Incorrecte, groups = DevisEnum.GroupeValidation.RECURRENT.class)
    private Integer                     dureeEnMois;

    @XmlElement
    @NotNull(groups = DevisEnum.GroupeValidation.ALL.class)
    private String                      loginUser;

    public RepartitionDTO() {

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = (prime * result) + ((this.id == null) ? 0 : this.id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {

        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final RepartitionDTO other = (RepartitionDTO) obj;
        if (this.id == null) {
            if (other.id != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!this.id.equals(other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

This object come from a MySQL Database loaded by NativeQuery with JPA:

```
public List<RepartitionDTO> findRepartitions(final DevisCriteria criteria) {

        final Map<Integer, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();

        final String req = RQ_REPARITIONS_CRM_BASE + this.generatePreparedWhere(criteria, parameters)
                + RQ_REPARITIONS_CRM_GROUP_BY;

        final Query q = this.em.createNativeQuery(req, RepartitionDTO.class);

        for (final Map.Entry<Integer, Object> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {

            Object parameterValue = entry.getValue();

            if (parameterValue instanceof List) {
                parameterValue = "('" + StringUtils.join((List<?>) parameterValue, "','") + "')";
            }
            logger.debug("Parametre [" + entry.getKey() + "] = " + parameterValue);
            q.setParameter(entry.getKey(), parameterValue);
        }

        final List<RepartitionDTO> repartitions = q.setHint(QueryHints.CACHE_USAGE, CacheUsage.DoNotCheckCache)
                .getResultList();
        return repartitions;
    }
```

I use two non standard things: 
A EclipseLink QueryHint to avoid loading from cache (the database is updated outside the application).

The annotation @Readonly to avoid bean validation by the JPA Framework automaticly after the request.

It's not a data problem, I thing it comes from JPA Framework but I'm not sure.

Can you help me please ? :)

Comment: Validator.validate() will at most return an empty set of constraint violations, but not _null_. That's ensured by the spec and also heavily tested. If something returns null, it is not the direct call to Validator.validate. Also, @Redonly has no bearing on validation and JPA per default validates on pre-save. I think you will dig a bit deeper and check for stack traces or other code which is executed. Have  you stepped through the code with a debugger yet?

Comment: I've debugged step by step until I can't see the source code. I know that validate returns at least an empty set but that's not the case.
The bean where the Validator is injected is itself injected dynamically using the Instance object.
Also I'm using Struts2 and CDI Plugin.

Comment: If you can see the source code, download or checkout the TomEE source code and put it on your debugger's path, that may help.

Comment: I will try thanks.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I didn't find the 1.7.0 source code to debug :/